# Paillier Cryptosystem and Protocol for Computing the Square of the Euclidean Distance Securely

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography, privacy

I am trying to implement the protocol that is proposed in [this paper](http://cs-people.bu.edu/zhu/Research/Privacy_Preserving/EDBT_337.pdf) (Section 3.2). I recently begin to work on homomorphic encryption and Paillier. Thus, my question might be too simple but I could not solve the problem in any way.

The paper says:

"Then the Paillier cryptosystem satisfies all the requirements
to compute the encrypted square of the Euclidean distance.
Thus, Equation (3) can be decomposed to..."

...to this equation:

[image]

However, I could not figure out how can I calculate Part III. I used [Kun Lui's Paillier implementation](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~kunliu1/research/Paillier.html) in Java and also following power method:

```
    public static BigInteger power(BigInteger m, BigInteger i) {
            BigInteger result = m;
            while(i.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) != 0){
                    result = result.multiply(m);
                    i = i.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
            }
            return result;
    }
```

Unfortunately, Part III could not be calculated successfully:

```
// Part I
BigInteger esumsqr_p = paillier.Encryption(p1.multiply(p1).add(p2.multiply(p2)));

// Part II
BigInteger esumsqr_q = paillier.Encryption(q1.multiply(q1).add(q2.multiply(q2)));

// Part III
BigInteger esum_pq = power(eq1, new BigInteger("-2").multiply(p1)).multiply(power(eq2, new BigInteger("-2").multiply(p2)));
```

If you help me to solve this problem, I will appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `power` function does not work for negative exponents. You keep substractring a negative number, so you will never reach zero. Use the following formula to compute it.

[image: negative exponents]

Thus, for negative numbers you should return `BigInteger.ONE.divide(power(m,i));`

Comment: You are right. I believed that the reason is not about the power method without doubt and so I did not even check it. It should work now, thanks.

Comment: I solved my problem by using a.modPow(new BigInteger("-2"), paillier.nsquare). Actually, 1/a^n equals zero for a^n > 1. However, your caution helped me to figure out what should I do. I still have no idea how modPow returns a valid integer result. Maybe it exploits integer overflow somehow and so it works for negative exponents as well.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the algorithm. Each party calculates results securely as you can see. I think some sub-methods will show the protocol in a more successful way. The method is below:

```
public BigInteger secureEuDistanceMD(int[] p, int[] q){

    // Server (Owner of q) - PART 1
    BigInteger[] enc_Q = new BigInteger[q.length];
    BigInteger sumsqrQ = BigInteger.ZERO;
    BigInteger enc_sumsqrQ; 
    for (int i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
        BigInteger bigQ = new BigInteger("" + q[i]);
        enc_Q[i] = paillier.Encryption(bigQ);
        sumsqrQ = sumsqrQ.add(bigQ.multiply(bigQ));
    }

    enc_sumsqrQ = paillier.Encryption(sumsqrQ);

    // Client (Owner of p) - PART 2
    BigInteger sumsqrP = BigInteger.ZERO;
    BigInteger enc_sumsqrP; 
    BigInteger enc_sumPQ = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        BigInteger bigP = new BigInteger("" + p[i]);
        sumsqrP = sumsqrP.add(bigP.multiply(bigP));

        enc_sumPQ = enc_sumPQ.multiply(enc_Q[i].modPow(new BigInteger("-2").multiply(bigP), paillier.nsquare));
    }

    enc_sumsqrP = paillier.Encryption(sumsqrP);
    BigInteger enc_euDist = enc_sumsqrP.multiply(enc_sumsqrQ).multiply(enc_sumPQ);

    // Server - PART 3 (Decryption)
    return paillier.Decryption(enc_euDist);
}
```